# C# Visual Studio - Having trouble adding an assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

So, I'm new to adding assemblies and whatnot. I work in Unity and I want to add the Puma.NET OCR software to my build, but I'm having a lot of trouble. Here are the instructions to integrating the code into your project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGzQQGm378jNEVlcmlPU3gtcTg/view?usp=sharing

In Visual Studio, I added the references to my project Puma.Net and puma.intercomp. It's not letting me add the last dll file for some reason.

I have a test script which says "using Puma.Net" at the start. When it compiles in Unity, I get this error:

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Puma.Net.PumaPage' from assembly 'Puma.Net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e8cf038eac46fae'.

I've been at this for hours and I've been trying all kinds of different things, but I can't understand what I'm supposed to do. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I can´t read the instructions you posted, since the site sent a "file not found" when I click download.  Anyway, you must follow these simples steps:

1) See if the NET version of PUMA is compatible with the same NET version you´re utilizing (eg. 4.5 or 4.6).

2) Add the reference to your project using the "Add Reference" and BROWSE the listed DLL´s of PUMA.

3) In the top of you main form, add "Using xxxxx" where that xxxxx is the name of the PUMA library

If it is not functioning, maybe it´s due to an incompatible library to UNITY - check this at PUMA site.

Comment: Sorry, here's an updated link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwGzQQGm378jNEVlcmlPU3gtcTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also, the site says that PUMA works with any .NET higher than 2.0. I looked up Unity Puma and nothing came up, so I'm not sure if it's incompatible or not

Comment: Probably NOT, since Unity is a new mode based on Silverligh (I guess), very similiar to Windows Phone programming. Try a test: create another WINDOWS FORM application and try to utilize PUMA. If it runs normally, the problem is related to UNITY (I don´t have neither VS2015 nor Win10).